# How can you prevent bogus high scores from appearing on a global high score list?

Tags: security, networking

Suppose you are designing a PC game that keeps track of high scores. In addition to keeping local scores, a global high score server is set up that is accessed by the game over the internet. Players should be able to submit their high scores to the global high score list right after they have completed a game, or later, from their local high score list. This must be a common problem; arcade games on modern game consoles often feature a global high score list that works like this.

My question boils down to: **how can you prevent someone from submitting bogus high scores?** Or, stated another way, how can the global high score server be sure that a submitted score was really produced by a run through the game?

The more I thought about this, the more I think it may be an unsolvable problem.

What you'd commonly do to verify that a message originated from a certain source is have the source digitally sign the message. You could certainly do that in this case, but the real problem is that the player, by having the software, also has the software's private key. No matter how obfuscated it might be, it can be reverse engineered, or even just plucked from memory.

Another option would be to send along a replay of the player's game to the high score server, which would quickly run the replay and verify that the submitted score matches the outcome of the replay. This doesn't solve the problem, but it certainly makes it more difficult to forge a bogus high score if you also have to produce a very complex replay that "proves" it.

Is this a problem that has a solution, or is it really unsolvable? Are there techniques used by the home game console developers to prevent this sort of exploit, or do they simply rely on the console preventing unauthorized code from running?

Comment: The presence of bogus scores is the result of people playing outside of the established rules.  So, in some sense, this is a people-problem and not a system problem (or one that can be solved at the system level).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a PC game where the score is generated by the client, this is not a solvable problem since the client is inherently untrustworthy.

The only thing you can try to do is make it harder for someone to submit a fake score.

Some thoughts:

- Protect the in-memory score.
  You can use API's like [CryptProtectMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380262.aspx) to hide the score in memory - a simple memory write will not work.  However, with an attached debugger or via injecting code into your process, they could still modify the score.  You can look into various schemes for trying to defeat debuggers.
- Protect the score en-route to the server.
  You can encrypt the data being sent to the service, as you suggest, but since the untrusted party has control over the key, this is merely obfuscation and offers no solid protection.
- Validate the score at the service.
  I'd be loathe to do this, beyond very simple checks.  A bug here will result in you rejecting valid scores.  It'll be impossible to distinguish between cheaters and strong players.

At this point, you really have to ask your self if the engineering effort is really worth it.  What if someone posts an invalid score?  What do you actually lose?  I would do the bare minimum to protect against a kid with a simple script.  I.e., don't have your score submission be just:

```
http://myservice.com/submitscore.aspx?PlayerName=Michael&Score=999999999
```

I would just use simple protection in memory against casual snoops, some simple obfuscation on the wire (hash the score with a server cookie) and be done.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, this is unsolvable.

I have seen many people try to obfuscate the encryption key. I have seen a few people include other sanity checks like time elapsed, or enemies remaining. I have never seen one that sends a replay, though of course it is possible.

In a website that will remain unamed, they setup a fake send high score routine that is easily found. If a perpetrator uses it, their IP address will be automatically banned from future updates.

Answer (score 6):

"Another option would be to send along a replay of the player's game ... This doesn't solve the problem, "

Really?  Why not?

"you also have to produce a very complex replay that "proves" [the score]."

Are you suggesting someone could fake the replay?  Reason out a super-high-score solution without actually playing the game?  Fake the timestamps and everything?  Pull a [Donald Crowhurst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Crowhurst)?

Why not just play the game rather than attempt to fake a log of playing the game?

Or... if it's that easy to fake a history of game play that leads to a super high score, perhaps the game is misdesigned.  If the game is "hard", the person must make all the right choices.  If the game is easy, then the score doesn't reflect the player's choices and is fakable.

Think of it this way.  Pick any game or sport.  Someone says that -- say -- Switzerland beat New Zealand in a yacht race.  You would challenge them by seeking substantiating details on the venue, the boats, the teams and the individual races to convince yourself it was true.  Certainly, they could fake it, but if they've got a rich set of details covering the race, then... how's that not "proof"?

Comment: Your point is absolutely valid. In practice, I *would* just send the replay data along and verify scores with it. I mainly asked because I am interested in learning about other useful technology-assisted methods of preventing this kind of abuse.

Comment: I completely disagree that a game where it's easy to create a sequence of moves that represents game state must necessarily be "misdesigned". Consider chess, for example.

Comment: @John Feminall: not "easy to create a sequence of moves" but "easy to fake a history of game play that leads to a super high score"  If you can fake a super high score, the game is misdesigned.  If you can simply claim a victory, that's no good.  You have to back that claim with decisions that lead to victory.

Comment: @S.Lott Your argument makes a lot of sense for thinking game, but not for timing games. It's very easy for instance to fake a Guitar Hero game history to get a perfect score, that does not make the game misdesigned

Answer (score 1):

Forget the cryptogaphic issue; if your code can be hacked on the local machine, how do you keep someone from setting a crazy high score artificially and then transmitting it using the existing trusted mechanism?

Until you can establish trust in the code itself, a crypto mechanism for the communications isn't going to be the real problem.

Answer (score -2):

Send the hash of the (software + a random salt) along with the score. Check this hash with the server. If it matches (meaning that the software is unaltered) accept it. Otherwise, the score comes from a "modded" version of the game. Reject it. The random salt should change every time the hash is generated (current sys time or something like that)

Check Quake III Arena source code. Their version was quite fool proof. Unfortunately, I don't remember the link now.

Comment: That is easily reversible, and not at all fool proof.