# PHP - How to avoid usage of my scripts in web browser

Tags: php, security, server

Let's say I have a server and a php file "addUser.php" which accepts some parameters like "name" and "highscore".

The php will execute an SQL query to store the data in the database. (I know about input sanitization to avoid SQL Injection.)

I want to know how to stop users from calling

> myserver.com/addUser.php?Name="it-a-me"&Highscore=9999

in browser or similar. I still want to be able to call this from my android app.

I know about User Agents but those can easily be changed using browser plugins etc.

So what's the best way to secure this?

Comment: _`myserver.com/addUser.php?Name="it-a-me"&Highscore=9999`_ suggests that you are using a GET request to send the values, try using POST instead. That way, the values cannot be manipulated in the URL. POST requests can still be manipulated, but it is much trickier...

Comment: @AdamMoffat, good to know, thanks!

Comment: @JustinT. Thanks, POST sounds a lot better, but could a User create his own POST request using a REST-client?

Comment: @KYL3R, yes, hence the _"POST requests can still be manipulated, but it is much trickier"_ statement :)... As AdamMoffat suggested, look into using CSRF tokens if you are concerned with that level of security.

Comment: This is harder than it sounds. Since the Android app is on someone else's device, you are necessarily accepting requests from other people's devices. You need some way of proving that the request came from the app, presumably using a cryptographic key, and you need to make that key difficult to retrieve for someone who has a copy of the app. You also need to protect against them capturing and modifying the request but leaving the key/signature, and depending on the actual use case, you may also need to protect against someone capturing and replaying the *same* request.

Comment: It is not trickier to edit POST parameters than GET ones, both are part of the HTTP request. Tools like [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) can help to intercept it, or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to craft it from outside a browser. Also, CSRF tokens are not a protection against the manipulation of requests, [it is only intended to prevent requests to be sent on your behalf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). This is not the solution OP is looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing cheating for on-line arcade high score board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488347/preventing-cheating-for-on-line-arcade-high-score-board)

Comment: Its not trickier to modify POST, you just have to know how, You can use POSTman and easily change it, also you can change anything an HTML form using f12 (debug mode), you cant rely on things like this to secure you site, you have to validate all user input, regardless.  What does it matter if John smith can put something in his browser no one will see it and if you give him an aproprate error page he will quickly learn that it's not much fun either.  Personally I would look at something like asymmetric encryption, even if you have to AJAX it back and forth.

Comment: So, what about a checksum? As long as my app doesn't get decompiled, the generator would be a secret. So you could not manipulate any of the http request without knowing how to generate the checksum. Are there common practices?

Comment: CSRF protection has nothing to do with this problem. Anything known to the client is considered known to the user too, anything the client can do can also be done by the user (ie. generating a checksum or signature). Of course compiling it in your game and obfuscating it may make it somewhat harder, but by no means will it be impossible. For that, the game should pretty much run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As your goal is to stop your users from cheating highscore, you have to implement a system to trust their input to your PHP API.

For exemple, you can look at this https://codeburst.io/jwt-to-authenticate-servers-apis-c6e179aa8c4e

[image: JWT Token]

And include highscore in the signed payload.

Comment: This will not help, because the signing key would have to be client-side so that the client can produce a signature. But then the user can sign anything too.